# Adding Collection Filters to Shopify Theme's Collection Listing Page

Tags: shopify, themes, e-commerce, liquid

I'm working on customizing a Shopify theme. I'm relatively new to working with the Shopify ecosystem. Currently, I'm attempting to implement filters for the collection listing page (e.g., mystore.com/collections) in a manner similar to the existing filters on the product listing page. However, I'm having difficulty finding clear information on how to do this and whether it's a common or feasible practice in Shopify development.

Is there a way to develop a filtering system for the collection listing page in Shopify? If so, what are the best practices for implementing this feature? Or is this something uncommon and not recommended?

I appreciate in advance for any guidance or resources you can share to help me better understand how to achieve this goal.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Relevant documentation is available on shopify help center: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/online-store/search-and-discovery/filters

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.